# Open Dropbox in File Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am developing a webpage for my company to manage some of our transactions. On this webpage, I display a list of related files fetched from Dropbox. Does anyone know of a way to allow those files to be opened on the desktop rather than the browser? Alternatively, I know that Dropbox's website allows you to open a folder in File Explorer (assuming the desktop client is installed, etc). Does anyone know if this feature is available through their API?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-explorer-file-manag/eokekhgpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkencdfkl?hl=fr

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API doesn't offer this functionality, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.